# PHP code for retrieving data from a google analytics account

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics

I am using GAPI class to retrieve data from my google analytics account. This class working fine for source and region dimensions, but I want to use this for events data retrieving. Please tell me is there any way to access evens data from google analytics account. If yes then please give me some idea.

Answer (score 0):

yes. here is a link for [event tracking dimensions](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/dimsmets/eventtracking.html#ga%3aeventAction)